# mean() does not work after slice() in summarise() in a grouped data in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, grouping, slice

I grouped my data and I would like to get the mean after omitting N lowest values in the group. My code looks similar to the one below:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  arrange(desc(wt)) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    Drop2 = if_else(n() >= 5,
                   slice(1:(n() - 2)) %>% mean(wt), #omit the two lowest value of "wt" then get the mean
                   NA),
    Drop1 = if_else(n() >= 3 & n() < 5,
                   slice(1:(n() - 1)) %>% mean(wt), #omit the lowest value of "wt" then get the mean
                   NA),
    Weight = mean(wt)
  )
```

I then get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `Drop2`.
x no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
i Input `Drop2` is `if_else(n() >= 5, slice(1:(n() - 2)) %>% mean(wt), NA)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: gear = 3.
```

Not quite sure why I get this error when the result for gear = 3 in Drop2 would have easily been NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `slice` is `.data` and it is mainly used to subset the rows.  Here `slice(1:(n() - 1))` doesn't have the `.data` input and only specify the index.  It is more appropriate to use `slice` as a standalone step in the chain.  Also, doing the `slice` inside `summarise` and then inside `if_else` makes it convoluted.  Based on the code, we just need to subset the 'wt' column and that can be done by directly indexing on that column

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  arrange(desc(wt)) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
           Drop2 = if_else(n() >= 5, mean(wt[1:(n() - 2)], 
                      na.rm = TRUE), NA_real_),
           Drop1 = if_else(n() >=3 & n() < 5, mean(wt[1:(n() - 1)], 
                      na.rm = TRUE), NA_real_),
            Weight = mean(wt))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#   gear     n Drop2 Drop1 Weight
#  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     3    15  4.05    NA   3.89
#2     4    12  2.80    NA   2.62
#3     5     5  3.17    NA   2.63
```

---

Also, as the condition is checking for length of expression 1, `if/else` would be more suitable

```
mtcars %>%
 group_by(gear) %>%
 arrange(desc(wt)) %>% 
 summarise(n = n(), Drop2 = if(n() >= 5) mean(wt[1:(n() - 2)]) else  NA_real_)
```

---

This can be done in a compact way with `sort` and `tail`

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% 
    summarise(n = n(), Weight_top = mean(tail(sort(wt), -2)),
            Weight = mean(wt))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   gear     n Weight_top Weight
#* <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     3    15  4.05   3.89
#2     4    12  2.80   2.62
#3     5     5  3.17   2.63
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks for the clear explanation and the suggested alternative workaround.